# Вставить консольную команду в код

Tags: c++

Есть код cgic который сохраняет данные в файл ini.
Как добавить после/или во время записи данных в ini выполнение консольной команды:

```
/opt/ip/params_ctrl -s set_wifi "ssid" "password"
```

где аргументы `ssid` передаваемые данные `wireless:ssid` и `password` это `wireless:password`?

Код:

```
static void doWirelessAddSave(struct setting_info *setting)
{
    char string[LEN32];
    int choice;
    cgiFormResultType ret;

    ret = cgiFormString("ssid", string, sizeof(string));
    iniparser_set(setting->ini, "wireless:ssid", string);

    ret = cgiFormSelectSingle("wifiMode", wifi_mode, sizeof(wifi_mode), &choice, 0);
    iniparser_set(setting->ini, "wireless:mode", wifi_mode[choice]);

    ret = cgiFormSelectSingle("safe", safe, sizeof(safe), &choice, 0);
    iniparser_set(setting->ini, "wireless:security", safe[choice]);

    ret = cgiFormString("password", string, sizeof(string));
    iniparser_set(setting->ini, "wireless:password", string);

    storeSettingInfo(setting);
}
```

---

из «ответа»:

При сборке ошибка

> setting.c: In function 'doWirelessSave': setting.c:1932: error: 'ssid' undeclared (first use in this function) setting.c:1932: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once setting.c:1932: error: for each function it appears in.) setting.c:1932: error: 'password' undeclared (first use in this function) make[1]: *** [setting.o] Error 1

Comment: Вариант с [system()](http://www.opennet.ru/cgi-bin/opennet/man.cgi?topic=system) чем-то не понравился?

Comment: Так: `system(("/opt/ip/params_ctrl -s set_wifi " + ssid + " " + password).c_str());`